# $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$ are unit vectors so that $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=\vec 0$. What is $\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec c+\vec c\cdot\vec a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Let $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$ be unit vectors so that $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=\vec 0$. How do I find $\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec c+\vec c\cdot\vec a$?

Comment: HINT: evaluate $$(\vec{a} + \vec{b}+\vec{c}) \cdot (\vec{a} + \vec{b}+\vec{c})$$ on one hand it is $0$, on the other hand it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=\vec 0 \Rightarrow |\vec a+\vec b+\vec c|^2=0$,$$|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+2(\vec a.\vec b +\vec b.\vec c+\vec a.\vec c)=0$$And since, $|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2=3$,therefore $$\vec a.\vec b+\vec b.\vec c+\vec a.\vec c= -\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The three vectors form an equilateral triangle of unit side length, so we know all lengths and angles. Now use the fact that $\vec u \cdot \vec v = |\vec u||\vec v| \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=\vec 0\implies (\vec a+\vec b+\vec c)\cdot(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c)=0.$$ That is

$$3+2(\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec c+\vec c\cdot\vec a)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

$$|\vec a|^2+\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec a\cdot\vec c=0$$
$$\vec a\cdot\vec b+|\vec b|^2+\vec b\cdot\vec c=0$$
$$ a\cdot\vec c+\vec b\cdot\vec c+|\vec c|^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=0$, then:
$$\begin{align}
\| \vec a+\vec b+\vec c \|^2 = \left(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c \right) \cdot \left(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c \right)  
 &=0 \\\
\| \vec a \|^2 + \| \vec b \|^2 + \| \vec c \|^2 + 2\left( \color{blue}{\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec c+\vec c\cdot\vec a} \right) &=0
\end{align}$$
Since the vectors are unit vectors, the norms are... You're looking for the blue expression.

Comment: See edit, this is better/clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting  with $$
(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})\cdot (\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})=|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+|\vec{c}|^2+2(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} +\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}+\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})
$$
$$
\implies 0=1+1+1+2(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} +\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}+\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})
$$
$$
\implies \vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} +\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}+\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}=\frac{-3}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 unit vectors, sum of these vectors is 0. This means that these 3 vectors form equilateral triangle. We have an equilateral triangle ABC and need to calculate $\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{BC} + \vec{BC}\cdot\vec{CA} + \vec{CA}\cdot\vec{CA}$.

$\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{BC} = -1/2$ because these are unit vectors, and the angle between these vectors is 120 degrees (the triangle is equilateral). situation is the same with other two products, and the final answer is -3/2.

No need for any magic tricks in this problem.

Comment: How did you decide that $120$ degrees will work rather than $60$ degrees? It can be seen after drawing the vectors but it is worth mentioning. One way to do this using $60$ degrees would be to notice that $\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{BC} = -\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC}$ and here angle between $\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC}$ (both vectors point away from $B$) is indeed $60$ degrees, giving then $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: agree, it's worth mentioning.